# Merge multiple vectors to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a data.frame `df`, around 300 seperate numeric vectors and a character vector including the names of all 300 vectors.

```
allNames
 [1] "x.1"  "x.2"  "x.3"  "x.4"  "x.5"  "x.6"  "x.7"  "x.8"  "x.9"  "x.10" ...
```

I would like to combine all of these vectors with the data.frame `df`. My working solution is:

```
for (name in allNames){
  if( length(get(names)) == nrow(df)){
    df = data.frame(df, get(name))
    names(df)[ncol(df)] = paste(name)
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to combine these vectors to the `df`? (Without using a loop or apply, with better memory allocation and faster processing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a simpler approach. Here's a reproducible example:

```
df = data.frame(abc = "a", def = "b")
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3
allNames = c("x1", "x2", "x3")

df2 = cbind(df, do.call(cbind, mget(allNames, envir = .GlobalEnv)))

df2
# abc def x1 x2 x3
#1   a   b  1  2  3

str(df2)

#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ abc: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
# $ def: Factor w/ 1 level "b": 1
# $ x1 : num 1
# $ x2 : num 2
# $ x3 : num 3
```

Comment: Or `cbind(df, data.frame(mget(allNames)))`

Comment: True, @RonakShah. That's even simpler

Comment: Thanks! (do.call(cbind, c(df, mget(allNames, envir = .GlobalEnv))) is giving back a matrix without nams)

Comment: @Funny, yep, that's why I changed my answer

Comment: `df[allNames] <- mget(allNames)`